# Как лучше всего убить зависший поток?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, многопоточность, потоки-данных

```
std::thread * tr1;
tr1 = new std::thread([&]()
{
    function();     // функция что то считает
    Sleep(3000000); // допустим это означает зависание
});
```

Запущенный поток по каким то причинам завис, таймер определил, что поток выполняется дольше времени. Как можно убить поток, чтобы он не висел в памяти и не выполнял вычисления? В потоке нет никаких мьютексов и.т.д.  Никакие переменные разрушится не смогут, туда передаётся указатель, который при обнаружении что таймер превышен задается в ноль. Больше поток ни с кем и ни с чем не контактирует.

Как его можно убить или поставить на паузу?

Comment: По моему это не просто, хотя с помощью boost можно использовать `boost::thread::interrupt`.

Comment: Покажите код, который определяет, что поток висит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если на винде, то

```
TerminateThread(tr1->native_handle,0);
```

используйте на свой страх и риск :D

Answer (score 12):

`std::thread` не поддерживает данную фичу, потому что так делать **крайне не рекомендуется**. Если у вас повис поток, это уже плохо, и именно эту проблему надо исправлять, а не пытаться городить костыли с убийствами потоков.

Если в потоке выполняется ваш код, то периодически проверяйте флаг выхода из потока или воспользуйтесь другим способом синхронизации. Если выполняется не ваш код, то ни в коем случае не трогайте поток. Никто не знает, что может оказаться в чужом коде.

Если вам нужны убиваемые потоки, то можете воспользоваться `boost::thread`. Или доковыряться до нативного хэндла `std::thread::naitive_handle` и воспользоваться специфичными для оси функциями.

Comment: поддерживаю. Как вариант, можно запустить "вредный" код в отдельном *процессе*, а не как поток. Процесс можно легко убить ([за редким исключением](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5648/1321))

Comment: +1, но вы бы разъяснили, почему именно не рекомендуется убивать потоки.

Comment: Разъяснения ниже

Answer (score 6):

Потоки убивать нельзя.

1. Поток взаимодействует с другими потоками, которые могут ждать каких то действий от убиваемого потока и убийство приведёт к взаимоблокировке (deadlock). Например: второй поток ждёт вызова SetEvent(), которого не произойдёт.
2. Поток может умереть и оставить текущий объект в несогласованном состоянии, что приведёт к неопределённому дальнейшему поведению программы.
3. Поток может работать с файлом, который так же останется в несогласованном состоянии (запись не будет завершена и файл будет испорчен).
4. Как правило у длительных блокирующих операций ввода-вывода есть возможность прервать выполнение, вызывать их асинхронно, использовать неблокирующее API и т.п. Например: вызывать select или poll с коротким временем ожидания, и в цикле проверять не пришёл ли запрос на остановку. 
   Можно открыть pipe и добавить его дескриптор в набор FD_SET для select() и когда понадобиться написать что нибудь в pipe для возврата из вызова select().

Comment: А ещё объект может как раз выполнять `new` и держать heap lock.

Comment: s/объект/поток/

Comment: на счёт heap lock согласен, а вот про `s/объект/поток/` не понял.

Comment: Я имел в виду, в предыдущем сообщении надо поменять слово «объект» на «поток». (Это была шутка для пользователей редактора [vi](http://lurkmore.to/Vi).)

Comment: ясно, да, vi хороший редактор, пользовался им 2 года, потом нашёл способ как из него выйти, и продолжил использовать Qt Creator

Answer (score 2):

если очень хочется то можно вызвать деструктор объекта, например используя умный указатель, код будет выглядить примерно так:

```
std::unique_ptr <str::thread> tr1 (new std::thread([&]()
{
function();     // функция что то считает
Sleep(3000000); // допустим это означает зависание
}));

if( tr1.joinable() )    // проверим, что поток запущен
    tr1.clear();        // в деструкторе потока вызовится метод terminate()
```

[документация](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/~thread/)